# Create pdf in Yii2 using mpdf extension: controller - view code

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I have installed the kartik-v mpdf extension.
I want to display a pdf in Browser.
Can you consult over the code?

In controller I have the following:

```
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;
.......
public function createPDF();
{
   ......
   $mpdf = new Pdf(...);
   $mpdf->SetTitle(...);
   ......
   $mpdf->MultiCell(...);
   .......
   // display in browser
   ..........
   ?
   ..........
}
```

So, should I render a view through this function to display the pdf or I can do it directly from the controller?
Is there another way?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try with google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to render a seperate view for pdf. you can render pdf directly from controller. refer this [example](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf)